# Calculating expected # of pack unboxings to solve 1/4 given puzzles

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, expected-value

It's been a while I studied Statistics or Probability, so I'm having some trouble approaching the following question. Any help would be appreciated.

Assume there are 4 distinct jigsaw puzzles, each of size 5x5.

One can unbox a pack which contains 15 random puzzle pieces from a pool of 100 (25 per puzzle * 4 puzzles). These 15 pieces also may contain duplicates and are not guaranteed to be distinct.

How do I go about calculating the expected number of packs required to be able to solve 1 puzzle i.e. gain the 25 distinct pieces pertaining to that puzzle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Let $P_n$ be the probability that you can complete a puzzle after opening $n$ packs, and $Q_n$ be the probability that you can complete a puzzle after opening $n$ packs but couldn't after $n-1$ packs.  Then, you have the relationship $Q_n=P_n(1-P_{n-1})$.  Your expected value is $\sum_n nQ_n=\sum_n nP_n-nP_nP_{n-1}$.

Now to progress, find the formula for $P_n$.

Comment: Does Qn imply that at (n - 1) packs the player must have had strictly less than 25 distinct pieces for the puzzle? Why is Qn != Pn?

Comment: $P_n$ is an increasing sequence, which approaches $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity.  $Q_n$ is a sequence that increases only until it reaches its maximum, at the expected value, at which point it decreases.